# How do I change my Json to Html output

Tags: java, html, json, api, converters

Hi I am currently developing a simple converter for Fahrenheit and celsius using Restful web services.

Currently I have values printing out in json using the following code written in java

```
//JSON Converted Values 
//Fahrenheit to Celsius converter
@GET
@Path("/fjson/{number1}")
public String FJson(@PathParam("number1") double num1){
    //String output = Double.toString((1.8)*num1 - 32);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String output = gson.toJson(new Result (Double.toString(5.0/9.0*(num1 - 32))));
    //Response response = Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    return output;
    
}
//Celsius to Fahrenheit converter
@GET
@Path("/cjson/{number1}")
public String CJson(@PathParam("number1") double num1){
    //String output = Double.toString((1.8)*num1 - 32);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String output = gson.toJson(new Result (Double.toString((1.8)*num1 + 32)));
    //Response response = Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    return output;
    
}
```

But I want to be able to call these methods say for example a simple page with a box and a button where the user enters the value and it converters and output in a simple html value say a `<p>`

Heres what the current output looks like
[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: Please edit your post and tags to indicate what language you're using, you will have a better chance of getting helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of, to consume JSON responses as HTML, is to use an [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) call with jQuery. If you're not to familiar with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (or Javascript) I suggest you do [some reading](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).  A primer for doing so (even though you're not using Spring) [can be found here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/).

Your solution might be a file with example html like below:

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<input id="change" type="button" value="Click me">
<p id="output"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var input = $("#input");
    var output = $("#output");
    $("#change").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            'url' : 'http://localhost:8080/api/convertor/cjson/' + input.val(),
            'type' : 'GET',
            'dataType' : 'json',
            'success' : function(data) {
                output.html(data.converted);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Minor suggestion: serve the html page up with your server, incase there are CORS issues.

If you are creating REST endpoints that are to be consumed by a client (such as a javascript client like above), then I'd suggest also do some more reading, as you'll quickly see that the above code doesn't help you built the client out.

Comment: Hey this was just what I was looking for so thanks, just one note your forgot your ; at the end here output.html(data.converted) but other than that great example

Answer (score 0):

Like above, there is a demo in jsbin(http://jsbin.com/befifu/14/edit?html,css,js,output). Which use a static json file to simulate the rest api.

Comment: your example link was also great thanks for the input